# How exactly does implicit number to string conversion work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wanna trick my friend by changing the `toString` function of `Number`'s `prototype`, like this:

```
Number.prototype.toString = function(){
    return '0';
}
```

So, when I do this, it works:

```
42..toString()   // '0'
```

But when I do the implicit number conversion, it doesn't work, like this:

```
1 + '2'    // '12', which should be '02'
```

So how exactly does JavaScript implicit number to string conversion work? What can I do to trick my friend this way? (It's not as evil as it sounds, trust me)

Comment: Any number concatenated to a string will coerce to a string. To take full reference about how that works, you should read the official ECMAScript documentation.

Comment: Not sure you can affect the primitive conversion. The above changes what Number objects will be converted to, e.g., `new Number(1) + '2'`

Comment: @VLAZ It still doesn't work by using `new Number(2)` :( I have to use `.toString()` to see the expected result. Perhaps javascript doesn't use `toString` function to do the implicit string conversion at all?

Comment: @HaoWu oh, right - that's because you need to overwrite `.valueOf` instead of `toString` to affect the primitive conversion. `Number.prototype.valueOf= () => '0'` will cause `new Number(1) + '2'` to result in `'02'`

Comment: @VLAZ It works :) Just wish it can also affect normally declared number and variables

Comment: It probably ends up being `String(1) + '2'`

Comment: @adiga it doesn't, at least in Firefox. I tried overwriting `String`. I expected as much, honestly, since I believe an internal conversion is used for `ToPrimitive`, not something exposed to programmers. Even if you replace `Number = () => 42` and then do `+"5"` you'd get `5`.

Comment: @VLAZ If one of operand is string, it [coerces the other to be string](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1). Probably an internal implementation as you said but is similar to `String()`. For example: `'1' + undefined` gives `1undefined` since `String(undefined) === 'undefined'` [ToString](https://es5.github.io/#x9.8)

Comment: @adiga my point was that it's *internal*, not `String(1)`, since `String = () => "foo"` followed by `1 + "2"` still produces `"12"`